# Google Cloud App stops working overnight

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Google App Engine and I configured my cloud application with Cloud SQL.

When I deploy it from eclipse it works immediately and I can see all my data on the cloud application.

The problem is overnight my data disappears from the cloud application but if I connect to MySQL with the Cloud IP it works and my data is there.

I realized that this is only happening overnight.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to minimize the amount you are charged for instances on per use billing plans, by default your cloud SQL instance becomes passive if it is not accessed for 15 minutes. The next time it is accessed there will be a short delay while it is activated. You can change this behavior by configuring the activation policy of the instance [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/cloud-sdk#sdk-edit

Comment: Ok I set to as always activated and this morning I woke up and it's showing some data but some functionalities are still not working... 

If I had to deploy it again from eclipse it will work fine.

Do you know why sometimes not all the functionalities work or they can tend to not work from time to time?